# DVC Experiment management workflow

Tags: git, dvcs, dvc

I'm struggling with the DVC experiment management. Suppose the following scenario:

I have `params.yaml` file:

```
recommendations:
  k: 66
  q: 5
```

I run the experiment with `dvc exp run -n exp_66`, and then I do `dvc exp push origin exp_66`. After this, I modify `params.yaml` file:

```
recommendations:
  k: 99
  q: 5
```

and then run another experiment `dvc exp run -n exp_99`, after which I commit with `dvc exp push origin exp_99`.

Now, when I pull the corresponding branch with Git, I try to pull `exp_66` from dvc by running `dvc exp pull origin exp_66`. This does the pull (no error messages), but the content of the `params.yaml` file is with `k: 99` (and I would expect `k: 66`). What am I doing wrong? Does `git push` have to be executed after `dvc push`? Apart from that, I also found `dvc exp apply exp_66`, but I'm not sure what it does (it is suggested that after `apply` one should execute `git add .`, then `git commit`?

I would really appreciate if you could write down the workflow with committing different experiments, pushing, pulling, applying, etc.

Comment: Hopefully if you read both https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/experiment-management/sharing-experiments and https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/experiment-management/persisting-experiments it will help clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did everything alright. In the end, after pulling, you can see that when using `dvc exp show` your experiments will be there. To restore the experiment available from your experiment list into your workspace, you simply need to run `dvc exp apply exp_66`. DVC will make sure that the changes corresponding to this experiment will be checked out.

Your workflow seems correct so far. One addition: once you make sure one of the experiments is what you want to "keep" in git history, you can use `dvc exp branch {exp_id} {branch_name}` to create a separate branch for this experiment. Then you can use `git` commands to save the changes.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, I'm still not sure how dvc does the saving, i.e., how does it know which parameter value corresponds to a certain experiment, without ever doing `git` commands. As for your addition: why would I need to use `git` commands if all works without it? Could you please make an example as an extension to your answer? I will then accept the answer. Once again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, if you cold explain what `dvc push` and `dvc pull` do, and if they are really necessary in the above workflow...

Comment: Ok, so:
1. Regarding the experiments - they are actually using a lot of git capabilities under the hood. DVC experiments are essentially a custom references (to grasp an idea tags and branches are references that exist in git by default). To read more about that I recommend going through blogpost about it: https://dvc.org/blog/experiment-refs

2. `dvc push` and `dvc pull` are commands designed for initial DVC capabilities, back when there were no `exp` and one would need to use git branches and tags to version the experiments.

Comment: If I understood correctly, `dvc push` and `dvc pull` are essentially not needed, given the above workflow, right?

Comment: Yes, when interacting with `exp` the commands within `exp` scope are enough.